# Unable to import enum into CTL

Tags: kaa

I'm currently working on a new Kaa iot application, and am trying to import an enum into the Common Type Library - but keep getting the following error:
Schema validation error: Schema com.company.project.SimpleEnumObject is not a record schema!

My avro description:
{
  "namespace":"com.company.project",
  "type":"enum",
  "name":"SimpleEnumObject",
  "symbols":[
    "ENUM_VALUE_1",
    "ENUM_VALUE_2",
    "ENUM_VALUE_3"
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

As described in the error message, your Common Type Library (CTL) schema must be a record. Read [CTL documentation](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/Common-Type-Library/) for details.
Look at the [Adding log schema](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/Data-collection/#adding-log-schema) section for example of the valid schema with enum field. Also, you can use [Avro UI sandbox console](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Getting-started/#avro-ui) to construct schema and show JSON representation.